# Can Enterprise WSDL be used as Data Source for Web Parts?

Tags: webservices, enterprise, wsdl, website-integration, .net

I am designing a solution which requires the Portal Team (front end team) to display top Level information as clickable link (Year On Year financial data) pulled-out from Force.com App. When the end user clicks the Year (say 2012) on the Portal he should be presented with the Monthly summary which should also be pulled from Force.com custom App.

I am planning to share the Enterprise WSDL and ask the Portal Team (.NET developers) to create Web-Parts leveraging the Enterprise WSDL as its Data Source. Is this solution viable? What are the gotchas' to lookout for?

Comment: If the external system supports http callout then i would use REST API with oauth to extract data from salesforce.How much is data volumes pulled in each request from sfdc?

Comment: Thanks Mohith, Volume is minimal and not a concern (less than 1K records); however not sure why SOAP API is not feasible here? Why the Portal team not use Enterprise WSDL to pull the required data?